# Create a 2D world

Tags: c++, 2d

Ive got a project for school that is to create the tanks game ( like worms or something else )

With a little research I found that the best way to create the 2D world would be to hold a bitmap of 1 and 0 to switch between background and foreground. So that I could load 2 images one for the background like the worms game the sea or something and another image with the map that is placed on it. Now because of that bitmap if I shoot something I could simply replace a 1 in a 0 so that there is a whole in the map..

With QT I could then just draw a canvas where I could display that bitmap.

I just don't find how to program this, maybe someone could help me out, where to start?

Comment: Do you mean mask the screen pixels with a value which determines if you should output the background or foreground at that pixel?

Comment: Yes I think. So that it is possible to change the foreground that there are some holes and stuff

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing with the 1's and 0's is called transparency and bitmaps can be made to encode this information in them, usually known as the alpha channel.

The key is to break down the problem into smaller parts and then tackle each small part - your question is very broad. So, break it down like this:

1. Create a window
2. Draw a bitmap on the window (no transparency - it's the background)
3. Draw a second bitmap with transparency
4. Modify transparency of second bitmap at run time

Comment: That order will get you started, but it won't be long until you want to write the background to a temp bitmap, then write the foreground, the write the temp bitmap to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Although I think the qt is not the right tool for that, you can start with [Graphics View Examples](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/examples-graphicsview.html). That should give you a quick start.